# Reinitialize ViewModel after coming back from another page

Tags: mvvm, viewmodel, mvvmcross

I use MvvmCross library for cross platform mobile development.

I've got the page with chat lists (ChatListPageViewModel). It loads chats from the container in the Init() method.

From this page you can navigate to the page which adds new chat to container (AddChatPageViewModel).

When the chat is added, I call Close(this) in AddChatPageViewModel. So, I automatically navigate to ChatListPageViewModel, but Init() method is not called at this moment and I cannot refresh my data. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Init is reserved for initialising new viewmodels - it's not really designed for refreshing existing ones.

However, I think you can achieve the type of application flow you are looking for by:

- sending a message from the AddChatViewModel when you add a chat
- or writing custom OnNavigatedTo, ViewDidAppear, OnResume handlers and using these to call custom methods on your chat view model

One example of the first scheme is in the CollectABull N+1 sample - https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-13-CollectABull-Part2 - when the collection service changes then it broadcasts a message allowing subscribed ViewModels to update - see http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com for walkthrough videos.

Comment: I was thinking about something like event aggregator with subscribers and notifiers, but it seemed like not the best way. But if it is, that ok, thank you!

And I'll definetely think about handling OnNavidatedTo, ViewDidAppear and OnResume. That looks like the best way to solve the problem