# Why is there a difference between navigating to the View (Back Button and ShowViewModel) and how to solve it?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

Let's say I have a ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public override void Start()
    {
        base.Start();
        //Important things would happen here!
    }
}
```

When I would use now `ShowViewModel<MyViewModel>();` from any other ViewModel, it will walk into the overrided **Start()** Method from the MyViewModel.

However it doesn't walks into when I'm navigating from a Back/Return-Button.

The BackButton was built like that:

```
class MyPresenter : MvxModalSupportTouchViewPresenter
{
    public INMobileAdminPresenter(UIApplicationDelegate applicationDelegate, UIWindow window)
        : base(applicationDelegate, window)
    {
    }

    protected override UINavigationController CreateNavigationController (UIViewController viewController)
    {
        var toReturn = base.CreateNavigationController (viewController);
        toReturn.NavigationBarHidden = false;
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

In the AppDelegate.cs I'm doing then following:

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : MvxApplicationDelegate
{
    UIWindow window;

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        //var presenter = new MvxTouchViewPresenter(this, window);
        var presenter = new MyPresenter(this, window); //Here my Presenter instead of the standard one

        //and so far....
    }
}
```

It's important for me to walk into the `Start()` Method from the ViewModel everytime - regardless if I'm using now ShowViewModel or if the navigation goes from the BackButton because I'm Subscribing there some relevant Eventaggregationmessages.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I don't have any knowledge about mobile development but is it something to do with the caching? Just like in browser application when you hit back button and previous request is a `POST` request the browser asks you whether you want to fetch the data again from the server by posting it again.

Comment: It just could be a similiar problem like u described. Anyway I don't know how to solve it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is there a difference between navigating to the View (Back Button and ShowViewModel)?

The Back button navigation is part of iOS - built into the `UINavigationController`

`ShowViewModel` navigation is something built into MvvmCross.

The `Start` call is part of the MvvmCross ViewModel construction mechanism - see [Wiki:How ViewModels are constructed](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/View-Model-Lifecycle#how-viewmodels-are-created-in-v3) - so it is only called when a new ViewModel is **constructed** - it's not called each time a ViewModel's View is made visible - which could be via back, via tab switching, etc.

> How to solve it?

If you really want to change the Back navigation so that it calls `Start` - then you will need to change `Back` so that it constructs a new ViewModel. You could probably do this using some form of special `UINavigationController` (perhaps via a delegate) and/or intercepting the left bar button items so that they perform `ShowViewModel` calls. Depending on your UI, you may also need to intercept other calls within the UI too (e.g. if you are using tabs, flyouts, fragments or some other presentation method).

Alternatively, if you just want to intercept View events like `OnNavigatedTo`, `ViewWillAppear`, and `OnResume` and to pass those on to your ViewModel, then you can do this by **not** using `Start`, but instead adding some custom `IActiveViewModel` interface to your ViewModel and then calling this from appropriate hooks within your views. For more on this approach there are some comments and notes in:

- https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/View-Model-Lifecycle#viewmodel-deactivation-activation-and-destruction
- [MvvmCross ViewModel caching and re-initializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857543/mvvmcross-viewmodel-caching-and-re-initializing/17867756#17867756)
- [How do I update the parent viewmodel when child viewmodel is updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405470/how-do-i-update-the-parent-viewmodel-when-child-viewmodel-is-updated/18408578#18408578)
- [Reinitialize ViewModel after coming back from another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581377/reinitialize-viewmodel-after-coming-back-from-another-page/17586049#17586049)